# Как обновить slug при update модели Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Чтобы автоматически создать slug при `store` нужно расширение Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable и достаточно написать код в модели

```
public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return ['slug' => ['source' => 'name']];
    }
```

Есть ли что-то похожее, но для `update`? Т.е. чтобы когда я вызывал `Category::create($request->all());` slug в БД обновлялся

Comment: Судя по всему вы какой-то пакет используете.. Это явно не "с коробки" возможности. Поищите в нём доки. Иветами моделей такое легко сделать

Comment: @InDevX Да, забыл сказать. Использую Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#onupdate

Если вы хотите повторно сгенерировать одно или несколько полей слагов вашей модели, вы можете установить для этих полей значение null или пустую строку перед обновлением:

$post->slug = null;